# Are countries either "developed" or "developing"?

Tags: meaning, euphemisms

The term "developing" feels a little like "deferred success".

Are all countries typically categorized as either "developed" or "developing"? Is it normal to describe a country as neither?

Comment: This is a terminology that describes the sophistication of a country's industry, infrastructure, and economic system.  It probably is viewed by those in the less-developed countries as a pejorative nomenclature, but it's easy to understand and is generally accepted (with, I think, written criteria maintained by the UN or World Bank or some such).  I'm not aware of a third category.

Answer (score 2):

> - **developed countries**  "are sovereign states that have a highly developed economy and advanced technological infrastructure relative to other less industrialized nations"
> - **newly industrialized nations** "rank somewhere between developed and underdeveloped countries. They have a more advanced economy but not all signs of a developed country."
> - **developing countries**, **less developed countries** and **underdeveloped countries** "are synonymous.  Such countries lack a sound industrial base and have a low Human Development Index (HDI)."
> - **the least developing countries** "refers to those countries at the bottom of a development index list."
>
> source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developed_country)

Comment: I won't argue with your research, but while "developing country" is a common expression - synonymous with: "You don't want to go on vacation there,"  I don't think you'd hear "developed country."  (It just doesn't convey enough info.) (US)

Comment: @Oldbag I disagree. In places where one might say *developing country* (*developing economy*, *developing market*, etc.), the natural counterpart is *developed country*. The difference is that there is a great deal more interest in the developing world, since their economies and populations are changing much more rapidly than in the rich / industrialized / "[More Economically Developed Countries](http://www.bbc.co.uk/education/clips/zdnkjxs)" of the world.

Answer (score 1):

The Economist's style guide regards "developing" as a [euphemism to avoid](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/euphemisms), noting that many people use the term even if the country is not actually developing (bold in original):

> **Developing** countries are often **stagnating** or even **regressing** (try
>   **poor**) countries.

Comment: Got a link for that?

Comment: @curiousdannii I do now.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

In the old 20th century view of the world this was the case. The world was neatly divided into developing and developed, every text book had a map with a rich north (including Australia, NZ and IIRC South Africa?) and a poor south.

These days however...this is not at all a common way of looking at the world. The usage of the word developing nation has really fell out of use. Other terms such as 'emerging economies', 'advanced economies', 'emerging markets', etc.... are used sometimes but generally one just doesn't see the world divided so neatly these days with the increasing development of China, India et all, the poor yet powerful state of Russia, etc...

Comment: "Developing nation" still seems very common to me. Do you have any actual evidence that it has fell out of use?